# Google 404 and .NET Custom Error Pages

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, google-widget

I've got an ASP.NET 2.0 website with a custom 404 page. When content is not found the site serves the custom 404 page with a query string addition of aspxerrorpath=/mauro.aspx. The 404 page itself is served with an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) status of 200. To try to resolve this I've added

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
```

I added the Google widget and have two issues with it. In [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) it does not display where it should. If I add it to the content, I get an "unknown error" on char 79 line 226 or thereabouts; if I add it to the head section the search boxes appear above the content. In Firefox it works fine.

So my issues are:

1. How do I make the widget appear
   inline?
2. How do I make the error page
   render as a 404 with the original
   name and path of the file being
   requested so that when I request
   mauro.aspx I get the content for the
   404 page, but with the URL of
   mauro.aspx? (I assume that I will
   have to do some [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) in the
   begin_request global.asax file, but
   would like this confirmed before I
   do anything silly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've handled the 404 by doing this in the global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request.RawUrl;
    if ((url.Contains(".aspx")) && (!System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(url))))
    {
        Server.Transfer("/Error/FileNotFound.aspx");
    }
}
```

Now, if anyone can help me with the google widget that would be great!

Comment: this is performance critical, you are checking if file exists or not every time on each request.

Comment: Correct, I could store a result in a dictionary or similar to use that to check faster...

Answer (score 10):

There is a new redirect mode in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 that you can now use so it doesn't redirect. It shows the error page, but keeps the URL the same:

"Also nice for URL redirects. If you set the redirectMode on  in web.config to "responseRewrite" you can avoid a redirect to a custom error page and leave the URL in the browser untouched."

- *[CustomErrorsSection.RedirectMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.redirectmode.aspx)* (MSDN)

Comment: Thanks but we are using .Net 2.0 in this instance, but I will keep the .net 3.5 sp1 info to mind.

Comment: Shoot i am really sorry, i must have forgot the 2.0 part of your post by the time i got to finish reading it. My bad.

Comment: No problem, I can use this as an argument for using 3.5 in future though :)

Comment: upvoted as this is still very helpful, and it's good to be clear that 2.0 is - bluntly - broken in this area