# Show custom error page in MVC 3 doesn't work!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I set custom error enable in Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

and, in Application_Start, put these:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    var routeData = new RouteData();

    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException)) {
        var httpException = (HttpException)ex;
        var code = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        routeData.Values.Add("status", code);
    } else {
        routeData.Values.Add("status", -1);
    }

    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("error", ex);

    IController errorController = new Kavand.Web.Controllers.ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

also I create an error controller like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Kavand.Web.Mvc.Kontroller
{
    public ActionResult  Index(int status, Exception error) {
        Response.StatusCode = status;
        HttpStatusCode statuscode = (HttpStatusCode)status;
        return View(statuscode);
    }
}
```

but, when an error occurred, the yellow-page shown, instead of my custom view! can everybody help me please?!
Thanks a lot, regards

Comment: What is the error on the yellow page. You have a lot of logic in the handler, and you are probably causing another exception to occur.

Comment: I know this was your question, but for me it's an answer! Thanks for this piece of code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to clear the error in `Application_Error` after fetching it:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    Server.ClearError(); // <-- that's what you are missing
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    ...
}
```

Also it is important to remove the `HandleErrorAttribute` global attribute which is added in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` static method in `Global.asax` as you no longer need it.

You may also find the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3/5229581#5229581) useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Darin Dimitrov; your answer resolve my problem, so thanks again and best regards. (^_^)