# Override `HandleErrorAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, error-handling

I want to override the `HandleErrorAttribute` with a new version called something like `HandleErrorsWithLogging`.  Essentially, I want it to log the unhandled exception to my log file and then proceed with the typical '*Redirect to ~/Shared/Error*' functionality you get with `HandleError`.

I am already adding `HandleError` to all my actions in the `global.asax`

Is this the best approach or is there some easier way to gain access to that unhandled exception for logging purposes? I had also though about an Ajax call on the Error view itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the `HandleError` attribute is indeed one approach into handling this. There are other approaches as well. Another approach is to use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which will take care of this so that you shouldn't worry about logging. Yet another approach consists in removing any `HandleError` global filters from `Global.asax` and subscribe for the `Application_Error` which is more general than `HandleError` as it will intercept also exceptions that happen outside of the MVC pipeline. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3/5229581#5229581) of such handling.

Comment: I have thought about using ELMAH, but I haven't really dug into it yet.  I guess my question really is more along the lines of 'Is overriding HandleError incorrect?' and/or 'Is there a way to get that error detail on the server side, using the MVC core capabilities?'  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: i'll accept your answer, although its not what I was looking for.  my question was how to appropriately use the core MVC components and your answer was -- use a custom tool.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom filter that inherits from FilterAttribute and implements IExceptionFilter. Then register it in global.asax.cs. Also you must enable custom errors handling in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>  


    public class HandleErrorAndLogExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The method called when an exception happens
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="filterContext">The exception context</param>
            public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
            {
                if (filterContext != null && filterContext.HttpContext != null)
                {
                    if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled))
                    {
                        // Log and email the exception. This is using Log4net as logging tool
                        Logger.LogError("There was an error", filterContext.Exception);

                        string controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                        string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                        HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

                        // Set the error view to be shown
                        ViewResult result = new ViewResult
                        {
                            ViewName = "Error",
                            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                        };

                        result.ViewData["Description"] = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Description;
                        filterContext.Result = result;
                        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```