# Not found page does not have 404 status code (IIS & Orchard)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, orchardcms

I have an Orchard project and am trying to implement a not found page. I have used the following implementation to allow a static page

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/264312

although I am running IIS6 so used the following to actually direct the user to the page.

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/404.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

The problem I have is that I checked in fiddler and the page is not being returned with a 404 status code.

I have being trying to work out how I would set this status code since the page is a standard html page, I was looking at adding a custom header is IIS

[image]

But couldn't find anything detailing what to put here

I also tried setting the 404 page in the error pages section

[image]

But this didn't seem to work

Can anyone tell me how I get the server to return the html page with a 404 status code?

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the response instead of redirecting:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/404.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

or handle errors as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3/5229581#5229581).

Comment: Have tried the above and I seem to just get the standard 404 screen when ResponseRewrite is in there and get my error page with status 200 when the redirect mode is set to ResponseRedirect. I don't know how easy it will be to do your other solution from within orchard,

Comment: is it possible to force that file to always be served with a 404 status code?

Answer (score 0):

I would "back out" your direct IIS changes in the "headers" and "custom errors" tabs and try -

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/404.htm"/>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to help, still getting the page served with a 200 status code

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this bug: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/16244