# Razor code in cshtml (error) page produce error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, http-status-code-404

I throw 404 error from application.
Page for 404 error is in the `/ErrorPages/Error_404.cshtml`
In this file I have only HTML code and it works fine.
But if I add some razor code it throws configuration error in browser.
I add for example **layout** or some `@Html.ActionLink(...`
This is error:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a 
>   tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root
>   directory of the current web application. This  tag
>   should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable
>   the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to
>   "Off".

This is how I produce 404:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)
{
if (city == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Some description");               
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new
                {...
            }
}
```

And when there is no razor code in error page it works and if not I get message from above.
When I set in web config 'mode=Off' then I get error message:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /CityPage/Navigation/Search

This is value from web config

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="\ErrorPages\Error_cp404.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Set the custom errors to Off in web.config and tell us the actual error message.

Comment: @Judo if he sets custom errors off, system will not render his error message page, but show the default exception stack. 1110, You should debug that page and show us actual error

Comment: I updated my question based on your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be attempting to render a `.cshtml` page directly. Those are Razor views. In ASP.NET MVC views are served through controller actions.

So:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/Error404" />
```

where you could have an ErrorsController:

```
public class ErrorsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You may also checkout the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229581/29407) for an alternative way to handle errors.

You might also need to add the following if you are running in IIS7+:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Your answer in link provided solve problem. Thanks. I was thought that razor pages can work without controller class.