# Change default view folder for custom Http404 error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404, global-asax, viewengine

I want to custom error pages in my asp.net mvc3 website.

So, I found this very useful post: [Custom error pages on asp.net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3) and it works well

However, my `Http404.cshtml` file isn't in the `Views` default folder. It is in a folder named `BaseViews`.
I already have my `_Layout.cshtml` and other views or partial views in that folder.

This folder isn't checked by the default `ViewEngine` (it only checks the `Views` folder and all the `views` folder of my `Areas`). So, I use a ViewEngineExtension and add it to the `System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines` collection in my `Global.asax`'s `Application_Start()`. All my application works perfectly fine and can access my layout and other `BaseViews` stuff.

I cannot tell the same about the `Global.asax`'s `Application_Error()`. This method ignore the previous view engine and only looks into the default view folder.
I tried to add my ViewEngineExtension in the `Application_Error()` method like so `ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new BaseViewsEngineExtension());` but it doesn't change anything. It's exactly the same line I use in the `Application_Start()`.

See my code for the `Application_Error()`:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 404:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                break;
        }
    }

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    errorController.Execute(rc);
}
```

My question is: How can I force `errorController.Excecute(rc)` view engine to search my Http404.cshtml view in the `BaseViews` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SLaks said, you should return the full path of your view in your ErrorController.

```
  public class ErrorController : Controller
  {
      public ActionResult Http404()
      {
          return View("~/BaseViews/Error/Http404.cshtml");
      }
  }
```

But it won't work because your error is overriden, so you don't get the result expected.
To bypass this problem, you can tell your application that everything is OK in your application_error with this:

```
Request.StatusCode = 200;
```

I hope it'll resolve your problem.

Comment: I still don't know how to define the view engine in the `Application_error` but it doesn't matter. Changing the `StatusCode` to 200 do the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Http404` action to return the full path to its view.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean? Can you be more specific please?