# MVC Controller Action gives 302 when throwing an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app. This app has some controller actions that return JSON. In the event that there is an error, I want to toss it back to the user. The general structure of one of my actions looks like the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
  try
  {
    // Do something here
    return Json(new { statusCode = StatusCodes.SUCCESS }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     // Log it
     LogException(ex);

     // Toss it
     throw ex;
  }
}
```

My problem is, when an exception is met, I've noticed in Fiddler that a 302 is generated. I believe this is a result of me using custom errors as setup in my web.config as shown here:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

I believe this because of the location value I see in Fiddler. I'm using custom errors for the purpose of my actions that actually return a View. Regardless, is there a way for me to bypass the custom errors setting in my actions where I'm returning a `JsonResult`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, but you'd have to tweak your Global.asax file to redirect errors like here: [Custom error pages on asp.net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3)

Then you can do different things based on what controller or action or request type it is.