# How to catch HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i redirect the user to a custom error page, when HttpRequestValidationException occurred.
I tried to catch it in my basecontroller :

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
    {
      if (exceptionContext.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
        {
          this.View("CustomError").ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
        }
    }
```

But i still get the exception :
A potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception occurs much earlier in the execution of the request and cannot be handled by the `OnException`method in a base controller. You could write a global exception handler as I showed in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229581/29407).

Comment: If i add the code Server.ClearError(); in protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext) action in basecontroller, then it works. But what is best practice? to catch this exception in global asax or in my basecontroller?

Comment: A global exception handler allows you to handle much wider range of exceptions that are occurring even outside your controllers. So that's what I would opt for.