# MVC3 Handling of exceptions in catch blocks and throw Exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I want to understand how can we handle rest service specific exceptions in MVC3. Any pointers?
Basically, I have a Controller and there might be multiple try catch blocks and throw statements for exceptions.
I'm a little confused after reading all posts.
Edit:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
        conReq = conReq.Get();
        conReq = conReq.ForUrl(Session["ServiceEndPoint"].ToString());
        try
        {
            conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

       return View();
    }
```

On throw exception, I need to be able to redirect to custom error page. 
I read through this post too:
[Custom error pages on asp.net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3)
but how do i handle for different error codes like 302 or anything else if my application is not running on IIS.

Comment: Can we see some of the controller code you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow is nice link for custom exp handling

[Click Here](http://outbottle.com/net-mvc-3-custom-ajax-error-handling-2/)

Comment: Thanks, the sample you have shared is really good. I will try it my next project for sure. For now I implemented using this approach- http://forums.asp.net/t/1505777.aspx