# ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Error Views issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I'm working on creating custom error pages in my ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I've already implemented OnException error handling and controller decorating with attributes, but I wanted to have custom error pages for URLs that didn't fall under any controller routes so I resorted to the Global.asax's Application_Error.

Following @Darin's (thanks btw!) response in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3/5229581#5229581), I have everything setup accordingly but I get an issue when the controller renders the view on the client side. **When it returns a view, it returns all of the HTML rendered inside of a`<pre>` tag.** I'm using Chrome's dev tools when I see this. This happens in **Chrome, Safari, and Mozilla (maybe more, I didn't bother to check after those)**. Oddly, the views render fine in IE though. I've googled around and looked around other questions and haven't found much on this. Would anyone happen to know how/why this happens, and a workaround fix for it? As a last ditch effort, I thought about getting the View as a string and using `return Content(...)` instead, but it seems a little much for what it's worth.

tl;dr - If I could have some input on why my view HTML is being rendered inside of a `<pre>` tag, that would be awesome! I'm sure it's browser-rendering specific, but I'm not going to settle on this only works in IE.

Controller:

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{      

    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;

        var vm = new ErrorViewModel()
        {
            ErrorMessage = "The page you requested could not be found.",
            StatusCode = Response.StatusCode
        };

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;            
        return View("PageNotFound", vm);
    }
```

View:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_GenericLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1 class="error">Oh No!</h1>

@if(Model.ErrorMessage != null && Model.StatusCode != null)
{
    <h2><em>@Model.StatusCode</em> - @Model.ErrorMessage</h2>
}
else
{
    <h2>The page you requested could not be found.</h2>    
}
```

Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            ShowCustomErrorPage(Server.GetLastError());
        }
    }

    private void ShowCustomErrorPage(Exception exception)
    {
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

        Response.Clear();

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Errors");
        routeData.Values.Add("fromAppErrorEvent", true);

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch(Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");
                    break;
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageForbidden");
                    break;
            }
        }

        Server.ClearError();

        IController controller = new ErrorsController();
        RequestContext rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        controller.Execute(rc);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix. Chrome wasn't recognizing what it was receiving, so explicitly defining the response's content type to "text/html" before returning the view fixed the problem.

```
public ActionResult PageNotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;

    var vm = new ErrorViewModel()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "The page you requested could not be found.",
        StatusCode = Response.StatusCode
    };

    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;            
    return View("PageNotFound", vm);
}
```