# Showing exception message from controller class to view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have defined a method in try catch block in HomeController.cs in my MVC3 Razor project. Now please tell how wil I show this exception message on my view page?

Comment: Please add code snippet what you tried. or error log if you are getting any error.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to show the error message on the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Model model)
{
    try
    {
        // some code...
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    catch (SomeException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and inside your `Add.cshtml` view you could use the ValidationSummary helper to display the error message:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Answer (score 0):

add model state error in HomeController.cs file catch section like

```
  try
  {
        methodThrowsError();
  }
  catch(SomeException ex)
  {
     ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
  }
 return View(yourmodel);
```

and in cshtml page display error like

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3/5229581#5229581) of exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a session variable in your controller 
AS :

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
   try
        {
            //////whatever code u want
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string m="mysession";
            Session["dep"] = m;}
return view();}
```

and use it as a flag variable..
 then in your razor view 
Show your message as :

```
 if (Session["dep"] != null)
 { 
    <h1>Whatever message you want to show in your view</h1>

 }
```

Rate my answer please if it was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(Model model)
{
    try
    {
        // your business logic if need
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```