# Redirect page in web.config for a certain exception thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a MVC solution, which works with authorization for certain URLs based on the logged-in user.

I had managed this problem by using a protected method on the parent controller which checks if a user is administrator or not. This is the code:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class ConfigurationController<E> : Controller where E : IPersistentVM, new()
{
    //SOME OTHER CODE RIGHT HERE
    protected ActionResult CheckPermission(string url, SPDCSS.Model.Rules.Enums.Permission.Permissions permission)
    {
        var user = Helper.GetLoggedInUser();
        if (user.UserTypeId == (int)SPDCSS.Model.Rules.Enums.UserType.UserTypes.Administrator)
        {
            return View(url);
        }
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Access Denied.");
    } 
}
```

And then, each inherited class calls this method this way:

```
namespace SPDCSS.Management.Web.Application.Controllers.Configuration
{
    public class ChartController : ConfigurationController<ChartVM>
    {
        public ActionResult Chart()
        {
            return CheckPermission("~/Views/Configuration/Chart.cshtml",M.Enums.Permission.Permissions.Chart);
        }
        //MORE CODE HERE... 
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to redirect for a specific view when I throw this exception, and I saw that most of people do it in the `web.config file`. I did it this way, but is not working:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Views/Shared/UnauthorizedAccess.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
    <!-- # some other code # -->
</system.web>
```

I think that maybe, the problem is on the status code which I had specified, but I don't what to use there. Any ideas about where the problem is?

Comment: are you testing in remote location?

Comment: No, i'm testing on localhost right now... on remote location takes a different status code?

Comment: Look at your <customErrors> tag. mode is remoteonly.

Comment: I removed this line, but still not working... =(

Comment: Better approach is to use application_error for custom errors, mainly because you will be able to log that error and do something with the data from it. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226791/custom-error-pages-on-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: I think that you are right, but in this case is not really important to do something with the exception. I only want to open another view in case of "this exception" happens...

Comment: try changing mode to "On"

Comment: I did it a while ago... i'm starting to think that is something with the IIS.