# Do "if" in Application WebConfig if it is posible

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-config

I want to do like this -
but I cent rite razor by web config.
Is there a way to write razor or do it in a different way to my goal will only manager see the errors

Apologize in advance for my English

```
@using Or50Core.Controllers;
@if ((BaseController)this.ViewContext.Controller).IsAdministrator())
{
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
   </system.web>  
}else{
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
   </system.web> 
}
```

"if" do the work in views

Comment: Does this idea help : http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Multiple-Config.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you would be far better off using logging. That way you catch all the errors (not just ones the administrator gets) in the log files/DB but the users only get a friendly error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the way that you would recommend to collect data errors on the site, or alternatively refer me to the Demo on the Internet

Comment: for the unexpected errors i would use something like ELMAH SCot has an article on it [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) expected errors i would use something like nlog [link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
@{
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (CustomErrorsSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

        if (section != null)
        {
            @if ((BaseController)this.ViewContext.Controller).IsAdministrator())
            {
                section.Mode = CustomErrorsMode.Off;
            }
            else
            {
                section.Mode = CustomErrorsMode.On;
            }                
        }
        configuration.Save(); 
}
```

this code needs to add `@using System.Web.Configuration;` to view.

**Edit:**

For manage users you can use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/Asp-Net-mvc-5-security-and-creating-user-role/) and for manage error page you can use [Custom Error Page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/618722/custom-error-page-in-Asp-Net-mvc/).

Comment: Replace your code in question with this code to your view

Comment: No
Because he probably can not change the settings at runtime
Secondly it can be problematic to my question because I do not want all users will see errors during the Admin login only The Admin seem possible to you

Comment: I test it,It can change web config in runtime. Also in if statement, you can manage users to see error or not.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but that does not help me
  Because I want to administrator see errors every site, and normal user will see the default error page
I know how to manage users

Comment: before of actions (for show error views), you can check user is admin or normal user and show views according to current user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `Application_Error` method in your `Global.ascx`. In this method you can check if current user is in Admin role or not and based on that you can show the real error or just a simple error page.

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
   if (!User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
   {
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
    routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    if (httpException != null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 403:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                break;
            case 404:
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                break;
        }
    }

    IController errorsController = new ErrorsController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
    errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
}
```

Here you determine what users see based on each error

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult General(Exception exception)
    {
        return Content("General failure", "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        return Content("Not found", "text/plain");
    }

    public ActionResult Http403()
    {
        return Content("Forbidden", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

BTW I find the answer in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229581/3667938)