# Create a filter attribute for a controller action parameter anti XSS attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss

I have a simple controller like that:

```
[CustomFilter()]
public ActionResult Index( int? page ) {
    return View();
}


public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext ) {
      base.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );
}

public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext ) {
      base.OnActionExecuted( filterContext );
   }
}
```

In main page (ASPX), if I type `http://localhost/home/index?page=<script>` (is an example of XSS, I guess) instead of `http://localhost/home/index?page=7` then the red page will appear (because in Visual studio I've installed AntiXSS addon).

How to create a custom filter for this type of attack and return the previous page without showing red page (with error) ?
Or is not possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the filter will never be called. you can do something similar in `Application_Error`

Check this question:[ASP.NET MVC app custom error pages not displaying in shared hosting environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706934/asp-net-mvc-app-custom-error-pages-not-displaying-in-shared-hosting-environment)

look at the question and the answer.