# How to return a 200 HTTP Status Code from ASP.NET MVC 3 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing an application that is accepting POST data from a third party service.

When this data is POSTed I must return a 200 HTTP Status Code.

How can I do this from my controller?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

In your controller you'd return an HttpStatusCodeResult like this...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeMethod(...your method parameters go here...)
{
   // todo: put your processing code here

   //If not using MVC5
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);

   //If using MVC5
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);  // OK = 200
}
```

Comment: or rather "return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);"

Comment: @dan, that's not needed. There are overloads that take an `int` as well as an `HttpStatusCode`.

Comment: to return a 204 status code do this: return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

Comment: @MEMark, I had to cast to make it work. Using .NET 4 & MVC 3 I was not provided with an override that would take an HttpStatusCode.

Comment: @ShawnSouth, I can't seem to find any information in the docs on what versions contain this overload.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413957(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @MEMark The link you provided is for MVC5, which is where it looks like that overload was introduced. MVC4 doesn't have it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult.httpnotfoundresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx (We're still using MVC3 here.)

Comment: Interestingly, I'm also finding that returning an `HttpStatusCodeResult` (in my case specifically, a `NotFoundResult`) appears to completely bypass the _customError_ settings in the Web.config. The user is instead presented with the ugly IIS error page.

Comment: Correction (I linked to another ActionResult): @MEMark It looks like that overload was introduced in MVC4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx.

Comment: @ShawnSouth, the link you meant to share is probably this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.98).aspx
I can see know that the left column in my link says MVC 5. I didn't get that it was a breadcrum... I thought that was the main menu. :)
(I like the regular MSDN way better, where you for each method get a list of in what framework versions it's available.)

Comment: @ShawnSouth, that is the way I would expect it to work. If you tell MVC to return a specific HTTP response, it would be very odd for Web.config to override this. IMHO that setting is only used for when a matching action/page is not found by the runtime. More specifically you could argue that returning a `NotFoundResult` from a controller action is indeed a bit strange. (What is the use case?)

Comment: @MEMark The use case is relative to our online Class Schedule (I work for a college), where the route URL denotes quarter/subject. If somebody enters a subject that doesn't exist I want to redirect them to the 404 page. I would expect that if I return a StatusCode of 404, the customErrors configuration would kick in.

Comment: I found and posted the solution to my situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22051444/1058872

Answer (score 57):

200 is just the normal HTTP header for a successful request.  If that's *all* you need, just have the controller `return new EmptyResult();`

Comment: You should use `HttpStatusCodeResult(...)` instead as it is much more explicit about what you are trying to achieve. As per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 55):

You can simply set the status code of the response to 200 like the following

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(parameters...)
{
   //others code here
   ...      
   Response.StatusCode = 200;
   return YourObject;  
}
```

Comment: Upvote because this allows you to send back other info as well as just the status code

Answer (score 29):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ContactAdd(ContactViewModel contactViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var job = new Job { Contact = new Contact() };

            Mapper.Map(contactViewModel, job);
            Mapper.Map(contactViewModel, job.Contact);

            _db.Jobs.Add(job);

            _db.SaveChanges();

            //you do not even need this line of code,200 is the default for ASP.NET MVC as long as no exceptions were thrown
            //Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return Json(new { jobId = job.JobId });
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(new { jobId = -1 });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly my use case, returning Json object but also wanted to supply HTTP_STATUS_CODE

Comment: For WebAPI returning status codes, use: new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, Request);

Comment: Best answer as it combines all use cases

Answer (score 14):

The way to do this in .NET Core is (at the time of writing) as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> YourAction(YourModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return StatusCode(200);
    }

    return StatusCode(400);
}
```

The **StatusCode** method returns a type of **StatusCodeResult** which implements *IActionResult* and can thus be used as a return type of your action.

As a refactor, you could improve readability by using a cast of the HTTP status codes enum like:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Furthermore, you could also use some of the built in result types. For example:

```
return Ok(); // returns a 200
return BadRequest(ModelState); // returns a 400 with the ModelState as JSON
```

Ref. StatusCodeResult - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom object that needs to be returned within the Status 200 response, you can pass a custom object as an OkObjectResult:

```
public IActionResult Get()
    {
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();

        return Ok(customObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In project root folder I was deleted `bin` folder then rebuild project again. This worked for me:

`D:\C# Projects\my_demo_project\WebApplication1\bin`

Good luck!