# How to set HTTP status code from ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

We're using OpenWeb js libraries on the frontend, and they have a need for the .NET middle tier to send them a specific HTTP header status code when certain types of errors occur. I tried to achieve that by doing this:

```
public ActionResult TestError(string id) // id = error code
{
    Request.Headers.Add("Status Code", id);
    Response.AddHeader("Status Code", id);
    var error = new Error();
    error.ErrorID = 123;
    error.Level = 2;
    error.Message = "You broke the Internet!";

    return Json(error, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It kind of halfway worked. See screenshot:
[http status code http://zerogravpro.com/temp/pic.png](http://zerogravpro.com/temp/pic.png)

Notice I achieved the Status Code of 400 in the Response Header, but I really need the 400 in the Request Header. Instead, I get "200 OK". How can I achieve this?

My URL structure for making the call is simple: /Main/TestError/400

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072804/how-to-return-a-200-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-3-controller

Comment: I believe what he actually wants is setting the status code in the response status line (which is circled), rather than the request header.

Comment: Requests don't have status codes, and even if you could do that, what would be the point of modifying the Request header information, you have already received it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There is extended discussion at [What is the proper way to send an HTTP 404 response from an ASP.NET MVC action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499817/1210520)

What you want to do is set `Response.StatusCode` instead of adding a Header.

```
public ActionResult TestError(string id) // id = error code
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400; // Replace .AddHeader
    var error = new Error();  // Create class Error() w/ prop
    error.ErrorID = 123;
    error.Level = 2;
    error.Message = "You broke the Internet!";

    return Json(error, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @SweatCoder Returning content with StatusCode 400 is not a good idea. Mobile phone browsers (chrome, opera etc) doesn't receive the content, only the status code, breaking your client code expecting json. Therefore using HttpStatusCodeResult like Nick suggested is the correct solution.

Comment: @CarlR It would be good to clarify what portion of the technology involved imposes that limitation. (MVC, the browser itself, the JavaScript libraries?)

Comment: @jpmc26 The phone browser.

Comment: @CarlR, modern [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RESTful) web services often return HTTP status codes with bodies explaining the error conditions.

Answer (score 61):

If all you want to return is the error code, you could do the following:

```
public ActionResult TestError(string id) // id = error code 
{ 
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(id, "You broke the Internet!");
}
```

Reference: [MSDN article on Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Otherwise, if you want to return other information use

```
Response.StatusCode = id
```

instead of

```
Response.AddHeader("Status Code", id);
```

Comment: HttpStatusCodeResult has the added benefit of keeping the controller testable. Using Response introduces a dependency on an HttpContext.

Comment: This doesn't work if you use the Action for jquery ajax call with dataType = json, because jquery expects json data back and an empty response above will error out.

Comment: The problem I've run into with `HttpStatusCodeResult` is that I have the actions called by AJAX returning `JsonResult`s, and `HttpStatusCodeResult` is not a `JsonResult`. You can just return an `ActionResult`, as a `JsonResult` is an `ActionResult`, but it makes the action signature misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get your json result into your view, try to add this :

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Before this :

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
```

More details on this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313866/9223103