# What determines whether the "success" or "error" function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've never understood: What determines whether the `success` or `error` function of

```
$.ajax( { ...,
          success : function ( retobj ) { ... },
          error   : function ( retobj ) { ... },
          ...
          } );
```

is called? Can my controller directly control which is called? I know it'll be called if my controller does something stupid, but can I force it to be called like

```
$.ajax( { ...,
          url     : 'MyController/CallSuccess',
          success : function ( retobj ) { /* this will invetiably be called */},
          error   : function ( retobj ) { ... },
          ...
          } );
```

---

```
 public ActionResult CallSuccess ( void )
 {
    // ...
 }
```

Comment: The docs didn't help? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: If the http call fails or if the script can not parse the content.

Comment: this also includes 4** errors and 5** HTTP errors.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112361/how-to-set-http-status-code-from-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: These use the HTTP Status. If the status is 200, it's successful. If it's 400 or 500, these are different errors. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can set the status code programmatically ie. `Response.StatusCode = 500;`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action method can control whether the `success` or `error` `ajax` function will be called via setting the `Response.StatusCode` in your action method.

If `Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK` then the `success` function will be called.

If `Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` then the `error` function will be called.

**Sample code to invoke `success` function:**

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'MyController/CallSuccess',
      success: function(result) { /* this will be called */
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('oops, something bad happened');
      }
    });

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CallSuccess()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return Json(new { data = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Sample code to invoke `error` function:**

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'MyController/CallFailure',
      success: function(result) { 
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* this will be called */
        alert('oops, something bad happened');
      }
    });

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CallFailure()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new { data = "error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```