# Find Empty Data in Listview from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I am trying to redirect to error page if the Listview is empty. I did try below workaround but doesn't seems to redirect.

```
protected void lvDetils_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("NotFound");
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with this? Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: does LvDetils.Items.Count==0 work for this purpose?

Comment: I have not tried this. But in which event should i use? I am using ObjectDataSource to bind the listview. but what is wrong with my piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this below code instead of your code

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == null)
```

Edit

or
try this code

```
if (lvDetils.Items.Count==0)
```

**New Edit:**

But you  have another option is .use  **lvDetils_ItemCreated**

```
protected void lvDetils_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("NotFound");
        }
    }
```

Comment: which event should i use for this?

Comment: I tried. It fires as shown i redirect to the page and for all the page content it redirect to "404.aspx" page.

Comment: Okay  .You want use lvDetils_ItemCreated event. Please see my above  new edited code

Comment: Thanks. It works now. So i had to use different event do like this. Just one small request. Is it possible to send status as 404 too?

Comment: You can  add this in your webconfig and more ways

please look these links

Answer (score 0):

Ok.I have got it done finally with the status code too.  Thanks Ramesh Rajendran.

Below is the code.

```
protected void lvEnglishMovieDetils_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("NotFound");
        }
    }
```

And in my 404.aspx i worte below code is below link

```
public partial class Custom404 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Page Not Found";
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```

Source of information for status code:

[how to set 404 status code for the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347281/asp-net-custom-404-returning-200-ok-instead-of-404-not-found)