# How to return a "fail" request with ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm learning web api with jquery.

Here is my plugin to make a post request:

```
$.postAPI = function (url, data) {
    let defer = $.Deferred();

    let onSuccess = function (data) {
        defer.resolve(data);
    };

    let onError = function (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: data || null
    }).done(onSuccess).fail(onError);

    return defer;
};
```

API controller:

```
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("{userid?}")]
    public IActionResult GetData(string userid)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        {
            return Ok(userid);
        }
        return new StatusCodeResult(401);

        // also try with
        // return BadRequest();
        // return Unauthorized();
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
$.postAPI('/api/user/getdata').done(function (data) {
    console.log('success:', data);
}).fail(function (e) { console.log('fail:', e); });
```

But I have always got this log:

> success: getdata

I want to make the request becomes `fail`. So, the log may be:

> fail: ...

My question: How can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to add this line (based on the comment):

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

to the method. But the problem wasn't solved.

Snapshot:
[image: 1]

Comment: For your request to fail (or error out) the backend has to return an error code like 404 or 500, I'm not sure jQuery can simulate this. Try change your backend code instead.

Comment: You need to change the return HTTP Response Code other than 200 from the server

Comment: @AgamBanga I've tried to add `Response.StatusCode = 404;` but it still was not working. I still got the same log.

Comment: @foo can you check the network tab what status it shows in the tab ?

Comment: @silkfire I've searched with keywords `asp net set response code` but I can't find the solution. what can I do?

Comment: @AgamBanga I have made a snapshot based on your question. What can I check next?

Comment: @foo check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347281/asp-net-custom-404-returning-200-ok-instead-of-404-not-found

Comment: Can it simply be that your userid isn't NullOrEmpty? Try commenting `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        {
            return Ok(userid);
        }` and just return `return BadRequest();`.

Comment: @Mike You can check again for my ajax. I didn't send any value for `userid` inside the request.

Comment: @foo See my answer.

Comment: No, its in the url. Check my answer below

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
this will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call "api/user" this will directly call your function "GetData" because you have no route for the function defined.

The "getdata" part in the url api/user/**getdata** will be interpreted as your "userid" therefor `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))` will always return true.

If you call "api/user" without the "getdata" part it should fail.

If you want to keep using getdata as url you can add a route for the function like so:

```
[HttpPost("GetData/{userId?}")]
public IActionResult GetData(string userid)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
    {
        return Ok(userid);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

> See:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Comment: Thank you! It's working. Can I have another question? After I change `BadRequest` to `Unauthorized`, why does the log still throw `404` error?. Image: http://i.imgur.com/o4DNsns.png

Comment: I mean: the status code should be 401 instead of 404

Comment: Could be that routing is case sensitive: try `[HttpPost("getdata/{userId?}")]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost("{userid?}")]
public IActionResult GetData(string userid)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
    {
        return View(new ViewModel(userid));
    }

    return StatusCode(401);
}
```